# lazy loading not working when on new saved objects, (when getting them from the context that saved them)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have this class

```
public class Comment
{      
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public long OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is that the virtual property owner is that I get `null object reference exception` when doing:

```
comment.Owner.Name
```

when calling this right after the object was saved (from the same instance of DbContext)
with a new context will work

anybody knows anything about this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is because you created `Comment` with constructor. That means that Comment instance is not proxied and it cannot use lazy loading. You must use `Create` method on `DbSet` instead to get proxied instance of `Comment`:

```
var comment = context.Comments.Create();
// fill comment
context.Comments.Add(comment);
context.SaveChanges();
string name = comment.Owner.Name; // Now it should work because comment instance is proxied
```

Comment: For anyone else looking for a way around not doing this, but say, using the MVC Binder (Which uses the default constructor), you can explicitly reference like this:

context.Entry(comment).Reference(x => x.Owner).Load();

Comment: m.t.bennett: That was very useful, thank you for your comment.